# seamless redeploy for java web application

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, geronimo

I am working at a startup, we are just about to roll out our first beta. Knowing that we will be having a good number of users, we want to have seamlessly deployment when we are adding new features.

I have worked with windows azure before, and I know they support seamless deployment, so I did some googling and [cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) was the first result.

So the question is, with what we have now (geronimo server, rackspace hosting), is it possible to seamlessly redeploy a java web application? If so, how?

Are there other alternative solution, such as using another hosting provider or use a different web server? (Because it is a startup, it would be beneficial if the answer keeps scalability in mind)

Comment: This question is very vague. what do you mean "seemlessly redeploy"?

Comment: redeploying the application without any downtime for users?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447164/deployment-and-maintainence-guidelines-and-strategies-for-large-scale-web-applic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632463/deploying-an-application-without-undeploying-previous-one-and-with-no-downtime

Answer (score 3):

If with a seamless redeploy, you mean an upgrade of your application without any downtime or restarting of your server, LiveRebel might be something to look at.

See http://zeroturnaround.com/liverebel

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods for doing this in the java world. If you don't use sessions (or use shared sessions between app servers) you can do a rolling stop/deploy/start of your appservers, taking 1 offline at a time and using a load balancer to ensure that traffic goes to the other servers.

Comment: Sessions are actually involved in this one, which I guess could complicate things.

Comment: Then you probably want to look at using shared sessions which can be very complicated to configure. You'll need to either persist sessions to a database or shared memcache. JBoss offers shared sessions out of the box. I've never used cloudbees... but PAAS can be VERY appealing to startups. We use GAE, but definitely not seemless redeploys.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard Glassfish has such feature, the reference probably ment this (Glassfish 3.x redeploy command) : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/6nmnj7q1h/index.html